# Ethernet not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, ethernet

As the title says, my ethernet is not working in Ubuntu 16.04. It actually stopped working a few weeks ago while I still had 14.04 installed and I decided to finally make the upgrade to 16.04 in hopes it would solve my problem.

The issue occurred right after I had done an `apt-get update`/`apt-get upgrade` and has continued to be an issue ever since even after the upgrade to 16.04. The wifi works just fine but I need the ethernet for work. I've scoured Google and tried many solutions but to no avail. Anyone willing to help me out? Let me know what info you need. Thanks.

`ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7317 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:109 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:542027 (542.0 KB)  TX bytes:37278 (37.2 KB)
          Interrupt:25 Base address:0x6000
```

I appreciate all the responses guys, sorry it took me a while to to get back. After some more troubleshooting, I feel my issue must be something to do with my work's router. At home I can connect to wifi and ethernet just fine, but at work I seem to be the only one not able to get through the ethernet. Any ideas what may be causing an issue like this. Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks again.

```
Listening on LPF/eth0/e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a
Sending on   LPF/eth0/e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x177c1d32)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x177c1d32)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.13 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x321d7c17)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.2.13 from 192.168.2.1
DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1 (xid=0x177c1d32)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.13 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x321d7c17)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1 (xid=0x177c1d32)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.13 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x321d7c17)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1 (xid=0x177c1d32)
```

Router Logs:

```
Aug 23 11:16:12 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:16:24 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPDISCOVER from e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a
Aug 23 11:16:24 [DHCP]: [SERVER]  DHCP_OFFER sent
Aug 23 11:16:26 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:16:28 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:16:31 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:16:39 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPDISCOVER from e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a
Aug 23 11:16:39 [DHCP]: [SERVER]  DHCP_OFFER sent
Aug 23 11:16:42 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:16:46 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:16:51 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:16:57 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPDISCOVER from e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a
Aug 23 11:16:57 [DHCP]: [SERVER]  DHCP_OFFER sent
Aug 23 11:17:00 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPDISCOVER from e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a
Aug 23 11:17:00 [DHCP]: [SERVER]  DHCP_OFFER sent
Aug 23 11:17:01 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:17:04 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:17:11 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:17:22 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPDISCOVER from e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a
Aug 23 11:17:22 [DHCP]: [SERVER]  DHCP_OFFER sent
Aug 23 11:17:23 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:17:26 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:17:29 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:17:37 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPDISCOVER from e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a
Aug 23 11:17:37 [DHCP]: [SERVER]  DHCP_OFFER sent
Aug 23 11:17:40 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPDISCOVER from e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a
Aug 23 11:17:40 [DHCP]: [SERVER]  DHCP_OFFER sent
Aug 23 11:17:41 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:17:44 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:17:48 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:17:55 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPDISCOVER from e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a
Aug 23 11:17:55 [DHCP]: [SERVER]  DHCP_OFFER sent
Aug 23 11:17:58 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPDISCOVER from e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a
Aug 23 11:17:58 [DHCP]: [SERVER]  DHCP_OFFER sent
Aug 23 11:17:59 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:18:02 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:18:10 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:18:20 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPDISCOVER from e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a
Aug 23 11:18:20 [DHCP]: [SERVER]  DHCP_OFFER sent
Aug 23 11:18:22 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:18:25 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:18:30 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPNAK on 192.168.2.13 to e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a via br0
Aug 23 11:18:45 [DHCP]: [SERVER] DHCPDISCOVER from e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a...
```

Thanks for all the help guys. Apparently many computers(and phones) were getting the same IPs. So we did a flush on the router and everything worked again. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @heynnema Error count is 0 so there are no errors.

Comment: Run `sudo dhclient -r eth0` and then `sudo dhclient eth0`  to see if you can temporary pick up an IP

Comment: @meccooll It never completed the process so I assume it never picked up a temporary IP

Comment: are you sure its the right port? can you post `sudo dhclient -v eth0` or try to assign static IP and see if you can ping gateway

Comment: @meccooll
Listening on LPF/eth0/e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a
Sending on   LPF/eth0/e0:db:55:a0:e8:1a
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x83add71f)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.13 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1fd7ad83)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.2.13 from 192.168.2.1
DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1 (xid=0x83add71f)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.13 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1fd7ad83)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1 (xid=0x83add71f)

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a beginner with Linux. Let me know if I sent you the right info.

Comment: Did you do `sudo dhclient -r eth0` before doing that `sudo dhclient -v eth0`? And it would help if you edit your OP and include that info instead of a reply. But if you did release "-r" before that then we might've found the problem `DHCPNAK` router for some reason doesn't want to assign you and IP (NACK=Negative ACKknowledgement) can you look at router logs to see whats going on

Comment: @meccooll I've updated the OP with the relevant info and I did a new dhclient command with the release beforehand (in the OP), thanks

Comment: Very odd behavior, for some reason the router is first offering and then denying you the IP. Sounds like a DHCP server issue. What brand is the router? Does it have any mac filtering firewalls or static DHCP settings on it? When you connect wirelessly do you get IP from same subnet? If so can you post `sudo dhclient -r {wirelessint}` and `sudo dhclient -v {wirelessint}` with your wireless adapter?

Comment: I will try to get you this info when I'm in the office tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First the basic troubleshooting...I'd make sure I get proper lights where the Ethernet cable plugs in. If its a short cord under 10 ft, I'd flip the cable so where it was plugged into the PC put into the network port and vice versa. Try a different port on the router/switch/hub/networking device if possible. If available use a different cable. If available try a different networking device. But....From the sound of it you have already tried those common troubleshooting steps.

So that said I'd try something simple, shutting all Ethernet ports down and bring them back up with these commands:

```
sudo ifdown -a
```

then

```
sudo ifup -a
```

If that doesn't work, check to make sure your interfaces are configured right. I've seen eth0 and p2p1 and enp1s0 for interfaces so I recommend to start with gathering information by looking at All your available interfaces with:

```
ifconfig -a
```

Then we can look and edit the configuration file, I use vim:

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

Make sure there are 2 lines reading:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

If you have to make a change to the file to save do `ESC` then `:wq` then restart the interfaces with the wonderful `sudo ifdown -a` and `sudo ifup -a` commands. May even want to restart your machine with `shutdown -r now`

You may also want to check the settings on the router/switch/hub/networking device as that may be the culprit and not your Ubuntu.

After checking that, it may be the hardware you are using. At this point I'd attach a spare USB Ethernet adapter and see if that would work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, really appreciate the help. Unfortunately, I've tried different ports and different cables on the work router and none of them worked. I've tried my home network and both ethernet and wifi work. I tried adding those 2 lines to my interfaces file but that did not work either. There are 3 other people working off the same router at work and they have no issues.

Comment: Have you tried a USB Ethernet adapter on the PC? The router is not the issue the PC is. I highly recommend trying it and posting results.

Comment: No I haven't tried that yet. I'll see if I can pick one up and try it in the office tomorrow. Thanks.